# Applying hover box over bootstrap grid layout on every 2x2 columns and rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid system that will apply a hover box over every 2x2 grid layout.

I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rjayako/bfwa0tte/

Basically first two to the left and second row first two on the left should share the same overlay box. And third and fourth first row AND second row third and fourth should share the same overlay.

I've created a mock up here of what I'm talking about.

[image: mock up]

Currently my overlay box looks something like this

```
.hover-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 430px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Unfortunately what this does is overlay all boxes to one spot.

I've been at this for a while now and I'm out of ideas. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/bfwa0tte/3/... or do you actually need a hover overlay element? I think the logic is helpful either way

Comment: @StevenKaspar this is amazing. I learned something new today. Please post this as answer and I will accept!

Comment: data properties open up a lot of possibilities. If you look into bootstrap.js files. You will see that is how they do a lot of things. I just left for dinner but will post as answer when I get home. Glad it helped!

Comment: @StevenKaspar The only thing I just realized is I can't add any text in the overlay since there is no overlay :S

Comment: just saw this comment after I posted. I can work on it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very barebones example of how you could accomplish something like this with just HTML and CSS. Basically what I've done is split the content into a 2x2 "outer" grid where each box has a 2x2 "inner" grid. Then, it's just a matter of absolutely positioning an element inside the "inner" grid and showing it on `:hover`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.category {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  position: relative;
}

.category:hover .hover-dingus {
  display: block;
}

.category .hover-dingus {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 27%;
}

.category ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.category li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="category">
  <div class="hover-dingus">Music!</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Alternative</li>
    <li>Blues</li>
    <li>Jazz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="hover-dingus">Music!</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Alternative</li>
    <li>Blues</li>
    <li>Jazz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="hover-dingus">Music!</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Alternative</li>
    <li>Blues</li>
    <li>Jazz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="category">
  <div class="hover-dingus">Music!</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Rock</li>
    <li>Alternative</li>
    <li>Blues</li>
    <li>Jazz</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectors` and `jQuery` and `data` properties. Another option is to reformat your HTML and use `classes` with `:hover`. I have included both options in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/bfwa0tte/4/). The code below is the jQuery option

```
$('[data-hover-group]').each(function() {
  var group_num = this.dataset.hoverGroup;
  $(this).on('mouseover', function(e) {
    $('[data-hover-group="' + group_num + '"]').each(function() {
      console.log(this);
      this.dataset.hover = 'true';
    })
  })
  $(this).on('mouseout', function(e) {
    $('[data-hover-group="' + group_num + '"]').each(function() {
      console.log(this);
      this.dataset.hover = 'false';
    })
  })
})
```

Here is it implemented with an overlay http://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/fbtu384t/2/